# Why is the infinite series $(n+2n+3n+...)$ not $0$ when $n \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I thought the $\lim_{n \to 0} n+2n+3n+...  = 0+2\cdot0+3\cdot0+... = 0 $

But we can write the above as $\lim_{n \to 0} n (1+2+3+...) = 0 (1+2+3+...)$

But $1+2+3+...$ goes to infinity and $0$ times infinity is not defined.

Comment: $1+2+3+...$ means nothing, you have to define a structure for it, e.g. $n(n+1)/2$ with $n\to \infty$ or whatever. Otherwise your question is senseless.

Comment: I agree with @user90369. Also, in limits, if you get something that approaches zero, times something that approaches infinity, it's probably not the right approach.

Comment: The sum is equal to $\infty \cdot \operatorname{sign}(n)$.  Even if you work with the extended real line, so that this could be viewed as a function, it would be discontinuous at $n=0$ in the same way that the function $\operatorname{sign}(n)$ is discontinuous at $n=0$.  The fact that taking the limit is not the same as evaluating at zero first stems from this discontinuity.

Comment: Briefly, you are imposing two limiting processes, one nested inside the other.  You can sometimes "switch" the order of the limits, but what you describe is a clear example of cases where the order *cannot* be switched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because limits and infinite sums generally can't be interchanged:

$$+\infty=\lim_{n\to 0}{+\infty}=\lim_{n\to 0}n\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} k=\lim_{n\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} nk\neq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\lim_{n\to 0}nk=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 0= 0$$